# After the login not redirecting to the pointed route in NuxtJs

Tags: azure-active-directory, nuxt.js, azure-ad-b2c, nuxt-auth

My application is using Nuxtjs 2(2.15.6) and I have updated the nuxt auth version from V4.9.1 to V5 due to the refresh token issue.(I have got the Nuxt server page issue due to the token is not refreshing when the user logged in and close the particular tab and once the user getting to the app, the server error page renders) The signup, signIn flows are used in the Azure ad.(I do not have much experience in the Azure side) After the update, I used a call-back component before redirecting to a certain route that the user preferred. But after the callback the application not redirecting to the preferred route either dashboard or surveys. Seems the token endpoint and authorization end points are calling with azure ad without any issue.

My nuxt.config.js auth

```js
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: false,
      azureAD: {
        scheme: 'oauth2',
        endpoints: {
          authorization: `https://${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.b2clogin.com/${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.onmicrosoft.com/${process.env.SIGNIN_POLICY}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
          token: `https://${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.b2clogin.com/${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.onmicrosoft.com/${process.env.SIGNIN_POLICY}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
          userInfo: `${process.env.API_HOST}/api/bff-admin/reports/users`,
          logout: `https://${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.b2clogin.com/${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.onmicrosoft.com/${process.env.SIGNIN_POLICY}/oauth2/v2.0/logout`,
        },

        clientId: `${process.env.CLIENT_ID}`,
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          type: 'Bearer',
          name: 'Authorization',
          maxAge: 1800,
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'refresh_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        },
        user: {
          property: 'data.user',
        },
        responseType: 'code',
        grantType: 'authorization_code',
        accessType: 'offline',
        codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
        scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
        autoLogout: true,
      },
    },

    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: `https://${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.b2clogin.com/${process.env.AZURE_B2C_ORG}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=${process.env.SIGNIN_POLICY}&client_id=${process.env.CLIENT_ID}&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=${process.env.REDIRECT_URI}&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login`,
      home: '/surveys',
      callback: '/callback',
    },
    localStorage: false,
  },
```

The index.js(The VueX store)

```js
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

export const state = () => ({
  accessToken: {
    emails: [],
  },
  isNotificationSeen: false,
  loading: false,
})
export const mutations = {
  setLoader(state, bool) {
    state.loading = bool
  },
  SET_TOKEN(state, token) {
    state.accessToken = token
  },
}
export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { app }) {
    console.log(app.$auth.loggedIn)
    if (app.$auth.loggedIn) {
      // const token = app.$auth.getToken('azureAD')
      const token = app.$auth.strategies.azureAD.token.get()
      console.log('token', token)
      const accessToken = jwtDecode(token)
      commit('SET_TOKEN', accessToken)
    } else {
      console.log('token', 'no token')
    }
  },
}
```

After the callback, its not redirected. The auth middleware is false in the callback component.
[image]

Token end-point[image] response

Call back component

```js
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-screen">
    <h3 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold mb-4">
      Authorization in Progress
    </h3>

    <div class="loadingio-spinner-wedges-jg70r74cjmn">
      <div class="ldio-bi654gh6r3i">
        <div>
          <div><div></div></div>
          <div><div></div></div>
          <div><div></div></div>
          <div><div></div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
export default {
  layout: 'default',
  auth: false,
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
```

The redirect URIs in azure side
[image]

Comment: What authentication library are you using?

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla-MSFT I'm using nuxt auth to handle the  auth in my nuxt app

Comment: Huge apologies for missing track of this. Do you still need help?

Comment: Kindly reminder